# tomcat 9 deal with the requests concurrently or sequence?

Tags: tomcat

https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/de6baf6e3a136b72a27ac788abc9955f4061ecb5/java/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardServer.java

From the source code below, it seems if there are two requests coming at the same time,  then socket = serverSocket.accept() is called for the first request, after finishing dealing with the first request, then it deals with the second request by calling the serverSocket.accept(), so it seems the tomcat deals with the requests one by one in the await() method, instead of dealing with them concurrently by one request per thread, however from the document below, it states "he ThreadPoolExecutor assigns the a TaskThread to handle the request." , however I didn't see how ThreadPoolExecutor assigns the a TaskThread to handle the request .Any one can give some hint how tomcat assign each request to a thread from the source code perspective ?
https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/83b3ea892aa03b4a8bbfdfe2b9a2e28755cb52cc/webapps/docs/architecture/startup/serverStartup.txt

```
    try {
        awaitThread = Thread.currentThread();

        // Loop waiting for a connection and a valid command
        while (!stopAwait) {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = awaitSocket;
            if (serverSocket == null) {
                break;
            }

            // Wait for the next connection
            Socket socket = null;
            StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                InputStream stream;
                long acceptStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                try {
                    **socket = serverSocket.accept();**
                    socket.setSoTimeout(10 * 1000);  // Ten seconds
                    stream = socket.getInputStream();
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
                    // This should never happen but bug 56684 suggests that
                    // it does.
                    log.warn(sm.getString("standardServer.accept.timeout",
                            Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - acceptStartTime)), ste);
                    continue;
                } catch (AccessControlException ace) {
                    log.warn("StandardServer.accept security exception: "
                            + ace.getMessage(), ace);
                    continue;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    if (stopAwait) {
                        // Wait was aborted with socket.close()
                        break;
                    }
                    log.error("StandardServer.await: accept: ", e);
                    break;
                }

                // Read a set of characters from the socket
                int expected = 1024; // Cut off to avoid DoS attack
                while (expected < shutdown.length()) {
                    if (random == null)
                        random = new Random();
                    expected += (random.nextInt() % 1024);
                }
                while (expected > 0) {
                    int ch = -1;
                    try {
                        ch = stream.read();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log.warn("StandardServer.await: read: ", e);
                        ch = -1;
                    }
                    // Control character or EOF (-1) terminates loop
                    if (ch < 32 || ch == 127) {
                        break;
                    }
                    command.append((char) ch);
                    expected--;
                }
            } finally {
                // Close the socket now that we are done with it
                try {
                    if (socket != null) {
                        socket.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Ignore
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused about the code you are reading.

The code in the snippet above is waiting for a `SHUTDOWN` command from a local connection. This has nothing to do with processing HTTP requests.

You are right: the `SHUTDOWN` listener is single-threaded and will only accept a single connection at a time. But, during the lifetime of the server, one really only expects to ever receive a single `SHUTDOWN` command.

Have a look at the [Tomcat configuration reference for the `Server` component](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/server.html#Common_Attributes), especially the `port` and `shutdown` settings.